# Comparison operators for subnetwork class

Tags: c++, network-programming, operator-overloading, comparison-operators

I'd like to define some comparison operator for a subnet class. My first thought is that we should be comparing the number of hosts in a subnet:

```
192.168.0.0/24 < 192.168.0.0/23
               ||
               \/
254            < 510 (evaluates true)
```

I'm not sure what should be done in the case of two like sized but different subnets:

```
10.0.0.0/24 < 192.168.0.0/24
            ||
            \/
254         < 254 (evaluates ?)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this comparison? The "right way" depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could order lexicographically the *pairs* `(size, address)`. That puts the smallest subnets first, and within one size, you sort by network address value:

```
struct netclass { uint32_t size; uint32_t addr; };

bool operator<(netclass const & nc1, netclass const & nc2)
{
    return (nc1.size < nc2.size) ||
           (!(nc2.size < nc1.size) && (nc1.addr < nc2.addr));
}
```

Comment: I still think it's not correct. Usually it's written: nc1 < nc2 <==> (nc1.size < nc2.size) || (nc1.size == nc2.size && nc1.addr < nc2.addr)

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak: Thinking generically, we don't like to mix operators. We define `<` of a tuple in terms of `<` of the members, and `==` of a tuple in terms of `==` of the members. Both need not exist simultaneously.

Comment: Or, `return make_pair(nc1.size, nc1.addr) < make_pair(nc2.size, nc2.addr);` to avoid having to get the code right?

Comment: @Robᵩ: Surely you meant to say `return std::tie(nc1.size, nc1.addr) < std::tie(nc2.size, nc2.addr)`!

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, that's what I meant. Sure. Yeahhh! That's the ticket!